# How to make the jquery datepicker default date to mm-yyyy (literally)

Tags: jquery, usability, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jquery datepicker.  The changeYear and changeMonth options are set to true.  This [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year) is exactly how my date picker looks if you click on the date input box.  See how they have to select month and year?

In my testing group about 20% of the users are forgetting to select the year (it's their birth date...dumb I know).  I'm trying to find a way to set the month and year drop down to 'mm' and 'yyyy' as to prompt the user to select both.  However, it seems the defaultDate option won't accept that kind of input and it just defaults to the current date.

I'm stuck.  Anyone care to drop some wisdom on me?

**EDIT**

I guess I didn't make it clear.  I want "mm" "yyyy" (the letters) to display in the drop downs as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Original post deleted. Sorry, misread your Question..

I do not believe what you are trying to do is available through the plugin options..

Comment: I'm not looking to format my date.  I'm looking for it to display "mm" "yyyy" literally the letters in the drop down boxes.